# Confusion with string pointers

Tags: c, pointers, switch-statement

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    switch(*(1+"AB" "CD"+1))
    {
        case 'A':printf("A is here");
            break;
        case 'B':printf("B is here");
            break;
        case 'C':printf("C is here");
            break;
        case 'D':printf("D is here");
            break;
    }
}
```

The output is: C is here.

Can anyone explain this to me its confusing me.

Comment: `*(1+"AB" "CD"+1)` => `*(1+"ABCD"+1)` => `*("ABCD"+2)` => `*("CD")` => ``C``. Switch doesn't matter.

Comment: @Stargateur that should be an answer.

Comment: Was this for some test or exam or interview question?

Comment: I'm not sure we need a question providing explanation for every pointlessly acrobatic piece of obfuscated code with zero context. There's the IOCCC if that's what you're into.

Comment: Well, we need at least t explain in a polite way that this code is not "for the realworld ", and deliberately obfuscated, if the OP can not perceive that. I would not be against closing such a question afterwards.

Comment: @underscore_d: This is not what I would call obfuscated. And such questions are used to probe whether students or job candidates have really learned a programming language, not just become vaguely familiar with patterns. Conversely, they can then be used to illustrate language concepts, since they expose details of the language specification that induce analytical thinking about the language. So they can also be useful tools for learning.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all, string literals only separated by white-space (and comments) are concatenated into single strings. This happens before expression parsing (see e.g. [this translation phase reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/translation_phases) for more information). This means that the expression `*(1+"AB" "CD"+1)` is really parsed as `*(1+"ABCD"+1)`.

The second thing to remember is that string literals like `"ABCD"` are really read-only *arrays*, and as such one can use normal array-indexing with them,  or letting them decay to pointers to their first element.

The third thing is that for any array or pointer `p` and index `i`, the expression `*(p + i)` is equal to `p[i]`. That means `*(1+"ABCD"+1)` (which is really the same as `*("ABCD"+2)`) is the same as `"ABCD"[2]`. Which gives you the third character in the string. And the third character in the string is `'C'`.

Answer (score 6):

In C, adjacent string literals, such as `"AB" "CD"`, are concatenated. (This is a convenience that allows long strings to be easily broken up over multiple lines and enables certain features such as macros like `PRIx64` in `<inttypes.h>` to work.) The result is `"ABCD"`.

A string literal is an array of characters. In most circumstances, an array is automatically converted to a pointer to its first element. (The exceptions are in contexts where you want the actual array, such as applying `sizeof`.) So `"ABCD"` becomes a pointer to the `A` character.

When one is added to a pointer (to an element in an array), the result points to the next element in the array. So `1+"ABCD"` points to the `B`. And `1+"ABCD"+1` points to the `C`.

Then the `*` operator produces the object the pointer points to, so `*(1+"ABCD"+1)` is the `C` character, whose value is `C`.

Comment: "So "ABCD" becomes a pointer to the A character." No, "ABCD" is an type of  char [5] not a pointer. array decay to pointer but don't become pointer.

Comment: @Stargateur: My phrasing is correct. First, “decay” does not appear in the C standard except as a joke about atomic variables. While evaluating an expression, the array is converted to a pointer to its first element. Thus, the value we are working with becomes a pointer to the first element, in the same way that `4*5` in `4*5+3` becomes 20 in the course of expression evaluation. The C standard itself uses “becomes” in this way.

Comment: You wrong except for "decay" term but it's more easy to say. `"ABCD"` is an array and will never be a pointer, `"ABCD" + 0` is a pointer. It's easy to prove `sizeof "ABCD" == 5` and `sizeof ("ABCD" + 0) == sizeof(char *)`.

Comment: @Stargateur: This use of “becomes” is typical English language. In the context of discussing expression evaluation, it refers to the value we are working with; it does not mean the original object itself changes. The C standard itself uses this language, as when it says “a normal long double value might become subnormal when converted to double”. In this context, the original value does not change; the verb “becomes” is discussing the change that occurs during expression evaluation.

Comment: "Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator, the _Alignof operator, or the unary & operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has type ‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points to  the  initial  element  of  the  array  object  and  is  not  an  lvalue.  If the  array  object  has register storage class, the behavior is undeﬁned.", don't use becomes but anyway, my bad `"ABCD"` alone is indeed directly converted into pointer in that case.

Comment: @Stargateur In any expression, a string literal becomes a pointer to its first element; it's actual type (or what `sizeof` would return, etc) is no longer relevant in an expression. So "So "ABCD" becomes a pointer to the A character." is a correct phrasing. If your objection to "becomes" is "no, the string literal doesn't *change*" then the same objection should be equally applicable to the word "decays" as well.

Answer (score 2):

Here, `switch(*(1+"AB" "CD"+1))` is evaluated like `switch(*(2+"ABCD"))`. *`(2+"ABCD")` points to character `C`. that's why output of your code is `C is here`.

`*(any thing)` is evaluated as pointer to a string literal.